# XSL Transform NameSpace

Tags: xml, xslt

I am doing some work with XSL and am having some beginner difficulties.

I obtain my source code by transforming an xsd into xml for starters. At the moment I'm just trying to be able to match against elements first, and focus on styling them later. I haven't found many information sources (approachable enough for me atleast as a beginner) for xsd to xml stylesheets which is why I'm basing it on converted xml so far.

A simplified version of my source code is:

```
<n1:Test xmlns:n1="urn:com:sam:types:test">
     <a>1</a>
     <b>1</b>
     <c>1</c>
</n1:Test>
```

My XSL is:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:pla="urn:com:sam:types:test">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:template match="/">

<xsl:for-each select="n1:Test">

<xsl:value-of select="a" />
<xsl:value-of select="b" />
<xsl:value-of select="c" />

</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm fairly unfamiliar with XSL and have been doing my best to work off w3schools but I'm struggling. I believe my issue is to do with how I'm trying to apply my namespace.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your stylesheet has two obvious errors:

1. You must have a space between `version="1.0"` and `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"`;
2. You declare `xmlns:pla="urn:com:sam:types:test"`, but you use the 
   `n1:` prefix. You should have:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="pla:Test">
   ```

   instead of:

   ```
   <xsl:for-each select="n1:Test">
   ```

You did not post your expected result, so I cannot tell what other issues you might have - but if you fix these two, at least you'll get *some* result.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, that has removed any error comments I was receiving from appearing, however I do not receive any data. I'm not too worried about the format of the expected result, just the result itself e.g. being able to simply output whatever is in the tags <a>, <b> and <c>. I am currently just receiving an empty response, whereas now I would expect to see 111.

Comment: Observing both of @michael.hor257k's points works here, I do get 111

Comment: Which environment or editor are you using? I'm testing with my companies editor and again with an online editor, and only receive the xml header: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Comment: Nevermind! it was because I was using a lowercase t for Test, bah. I've applied your example to my larger source code and got it working! I've since added some styling and everything is working like a dream. Thank you both for your help! This gets rid of a bunch of my stress!